# Can f(x)*g(x) have less local extrema than f(x) if g(x) is increasing and bigger than 0?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, continuity, maxima-minima

Can I find two functions that satisfy these conditions?

Both functions have to be continous and differentiable.

Does the problem change if g(x) has to be strictly increasing or not differentiable?

Comment: What do you mean by "total local extrema"?

Comment: @msgcas
I mean the total number of local extrema the function has. How should I rephrase this in my question? Thanks.

Comment: @msgcas
Just realized that it’s clearer once I remove the word ‘total’. Thanks.

Comment: You may want to think about $f(x)=xe^{-\vert x\vert}$. How many local extrema does it have?  What is the function you may want to multiply it with?

Comment: @msgcas Thanks! Your function loses one local extrema once I multiply it with e^x. Guess this question is solved then.

Comment: @Saha That is not correct. Firstly, you probably meant $x^4$ and not $x^5$, secondly (and more importantly) your function $f\cdot g$ has got infinitely many local extrema not none.